# Why should we worry about the hormone level in our body OR bodies?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

This is just one example:

> Why should we worry about the hormone level in our body **or** bodies?

Similarly,

> In postmortem, doctors found that they all (dead) had poison in their stomach **or** stomaches?

Okay, is there any example sentence that uses *"...plural....and singular something that belong to that plural?"* as in my first options of 'body' and 'stomach'?

Frankly, I don't find any problem in using *body* over *bodies* there. It's understandable.

Comment: Offtopic, but your second sentence can be misinterpreted in a very weird way as the doctors having poison in their (the doctors') stomach.

Comment: @oerkelens corrected

Comment: _Frankly, I don't find any problem in using body over bodies there. It's understandable._ That's exactly how I feel. However, there's still the question about whether or not one or the other could be regarded as grammatically incorrect (which you would want to know if you were, say, writing an academic paper).

Comment: This might also be useful: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36130/is-it-all-right-to-say-all-men-have-one-head.

Answer (score 1):

There's no inherent problem with using singular or plural in either case - depending on how many objects are being talked about.

If multiple people own a single item you can use the singular - multiple people having a single body or stomach shared by all members of the group (not one per person, as is the norm) is practically unheard of.

For example:

> Why should we worry about the hormone level in our body?

is fine if three individuals shared a single body like these fellows:
[image: Three people one body.]

Not so great in most situations.

On the other hand - a family of four people and one dog could say

> "We love our dog."

because there is only one dog - whereas a single person with four dogs would say

> "I love my dogs."

Comment: I'm pretty clear about using pronouns in that way. The question is something else.

Comment: @MaulikV Answer adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [an answer I gave to a very similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/our-bodies-or-our-bodys), I am inclined to say that because you are speaking of multiple physical bodies, you should use the plural form.  That is, by using "we" you are referring to more than one person, and each person has their own body, so more than one body is under consideration, and therefore the plural is called for.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was leaning toward. But think for a while, singular doesn't look u.at bad too!